# Knots with everywhere positive curvature

Tags: algebraic-curves, knot-theory, curvature

A naive question that my searches have not resolved:

> ***Q***. Can every knot be realized by a curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with strictly positive
> curvature at every point?

Comment: Can't you simply take any curve that realizes the knot, and then replace that curve with a helix in some frame along it?

Comment: @mlk: Seems plausible. Perhaps joining the subsections of helices could be problematical?

Comment: I am not sure how the algebraic-curves tag in your question applies, but on the level of smooth curves there should not be a problem. You can always parametrize a small neighborhood of the curve as a long cylinder. You may get some twist in the end but that you can correct with another partial winding of the helix.

Comment: @mlk seems right. Assume the knot $\gamma$ parametrized by $[0,2\pi]$, take a smooth othonormal frame $(\gamma'(t),n_1(t),n_2(t)$ and consider $\sigma(t)=\gamma(t)+\varepsilon(cos(Nt) n_1(t)+sin(Nt) n_2(t))$ for small enough $\varepsilon$ and large enough $N$, and you are done.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner: Thanks. I am convinced now. mlk: Nice idea!